# In D3.js, is it possible to pass a lookup function for tick labels to an ordinal scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My data (huge dataset) have multiple String attributes, which for the sake of compression and comparison speed are stored as an array of indices with each datum. The actual values can be looked up in a separate array using those indices.

I don’t really need the actual values for any computation. But when plotting the data, as a very last step, I would like the axis labels to give the values instead of the indices.

Is there a way to tell an ordinal D3 axis to not take the corresponding scale’s domain’s values directly, but rather pass them to a short lookup function?
In my case, being able to specify the array would even be sufficient.

I know I could define the domain with the values instead of the indices directly, but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tickFormat` to do this. It receives a function whose primary role is to give a custom format to tick values (number of trailing zeros, date formats etc.), but you can make one that would lookup your data table.

See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat for documentation.